# How to install cronie on Alpine Linux 3?

Tags: cron, alpine-linux

I am not sure, how to install cronie on Alpine Linux as one software requires it.
If no package available can I compile and install it, what will be steps?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question. Try [unix.se]

Comment: @KeithThompson My stack is overflowing, does that satisfies condition? :D

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem on Alpine Docker image and I just used crontab for it.

```
echo "0 0 * * * /run/my/application" >> /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root
```

Answer (score -1):

The Fedora `cronie` package is [their version](https://fedorahosted.org/cronie/) of the standard Linux cron software. It's tough to tell what your software requires, but it probably just needs cron. What software are you trying to install? You may be able to adjust the package definition so that your installed version of cron is an acceptable alternative to `cronie`.

Comment: It is possible to compile cronie on Alpine Linx if no package is available? how?